# Is there a limit for the width of a canvas

Tags: canvas, tcl, tk-toolkit

Is there a limit for the value of the attribute "width" of a canvas ?

In the following example, I create a Canvas in a ScrolledWindow.

```
# Packages
package require BWidget

# Mainframe
set mfr [MainFrame .mfr -textvariable "Test"]
pack $mfr -fill both -expand yes

# Create a Paned Window with two panes
set pw1 [PanedWindow [$mfr getframe].pw1 -side left]
set pat [$pw1 add -minsize 200]
set pai [$pw1 add -minsize 200]
pack $pw1 -fill both -expand yes -anchor nw

# Create a frame for each pane
set tft [TitleFrame $pat.tft -text "Scrollable Canvas"]
set tfi [TitleFrame $pai.tfi -text "Informations"]
pack $tft -fill both -expand yes -anchor nw
pack $tfi -fill both -expand yes -anchor nw

# Create a canvas inside a ScrolledWindow for the first pane
set swt [ScrolledWindow [$tft getframe].swt -relief sunken -borderwidth 2 -scrollbar horizontal -auto none]
set sft [ScrollableFrame $swt.sft -width 50000 -height 200]
$swt setwidget $sft
set tab [canvas [$sft getframe].tab -width 50000 -height 200 -background black]
# Draw an horizontal line on the canvas
$tab create line 0 100 50000 100 -width 1 -fill white

pack $tab -fill both -expand yes -anchor nw
pack $swt -fill both -expand yes -anchor nw

# Create a ScrolledWindow for the second pane
set swl [ScrolledWindow [$tfi getframe].swl -relief sunken -borderwidth 2 -scrollbar vertical -auto both]
pack $swl -expand yes -fill both

# Display the window manager
wm minsize . 600 350
wm deiconify .
wm protocol . WM_DELETE_WINDOW {exit}
bind . <Control-q> {exit}
```

In this example, I used a width of "50 000" for the canvas, but when I use the scrollbar the black box of the canvas ends before. The same issue also affects the horizontal line which is drawn on the canvas.

Do I missed something ?
  Is there a known limit for the "width" attribute of the canvas ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes, I haven't looked recently at recent browser canvas size maximums but they used to be 8k-12k width or height and a maximum 2mb pixel maximum. IMHO, excessive canvas sizes are usually created to "flatten" design requirements. If you run into problems as a result of your canvas size (eg, you have exceeded the browser's maximum size), then you should take that as a signal to change your design to be less flat.

Comment: The size of buffer required for rendering depends purely on the size of the viewport (the visible part of the canvas). But coordinate calculations go a bit wonky when drawing things with coords out of the `short` range (_after_ translation to viewport coordinates) that are visible in the viewport.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things get a bit funky if you make them larger than 32,000 (strictly 32767, the limit of a signed C `short`) particularly at the rendering layer (and *definitely* don't make the canvas viewport that size!). However, the underlying canvas model uses IEEE `double`s to store the coordinates, so there's no reason why you couldn't have things go off that far. You just must keep the size of individual objects down.

This is all a legacy of X11, which uses 16-bit values for coordinates and dimensions in quite a few key structures. Changing this is both logically easy and a lot of work in practice (the assumptions are all over the place).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
So I can draw graphical items on the canvas with coordinates higher than its view size, and I have to use a scrollbar to move the viewable part of the canvas ?